# Where accurately to set dependencies for modules to import, using "The Haskell Tool Stack"?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

### Background

There is multiple places in file package.yaml to set dependencies.

```
name:                Test1

...

extra-source-files:
- README.md
- ChangeLog.md

...

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  Test1-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - Test1
    - directory

tests:
  Test1-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - Test1
```

### Further background

In an Haskell module that I created, I imported the package "Directory" like this...

```
import qualified System.Directory as Dir
```

...and used it like this...

```
Dir.removeFile
```

I made shure that the package "Directory is installed by executing...

```
stack install directory
```

When building the application ("Main.hs") plus library (./src) the compiler "says" ...

```
[ 7 of 10] Compiling XYZ

src\XYZ.hs:16:1: error:
    Could not load module `System.Directory'
    It is a member of the hidden package `directory-1.3.6.0'.
    Perhaps you need to add `directory' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
16 | import qualified System.Directory as Dir
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

According to what I read after searching in stackoverflow, google, and here "https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/", and in order to include the package "Directory" I manipulated the "stack.yaml" and "package.yaml" - but it did not work, nor I could find a resource explaining how to that poperly works.

### The actual question

There is different sections of dependencies and ways to list.

I read this one and it didn't work.

Where accurately to set dependencies for modules to import?

### Notes

A similar question ("External dependencies, Haskell, stack: should I modify something or 'import' suppose to be sufficient?") has almost answered my question.

While I still get downvotes, I can't deleted this question, because I have got already answers, that's why I tried to provide a more accurate question - and hoping to be able to provide an accurate answer, as well.

See also my 2nd comment, and the newly edited answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant part of the error message is this one:

> Perhaps you need to add `directory` to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

If you want to do so: In `package.yaml`, add `- directory` to the **first** `dependencies:` field.

```
name:                xyz
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "githubuser/xyz"
license:             none
author:              "..."
maintainer:          "...@..."
copyright:           "(c) 2021 ..."

extra-source-files:
- README.md
- ChangeLog.md

# ...
description:         Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/...>

dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- directory

library:
  source-dirs: src
  ghc-options:
  - -O2
  - -threaded
  - -rtsopts
  - -with-rtsopts=-N

executables:
  xyz:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -O2
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - xyz

tests:
  xyz-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - xyz
```

NOTE: To add `- directory` below `executables:` is not sufficient.

Indentation of `- directory` is allowed but all dependencies have to have the same indentation. Hence, the following is also OK:

```
dependencies:
  - base >= 4.7 && < 5
  - directory
```

### Further notes

Many people don't use `hpack` (they remove `package.yaml` and edit the `.cabal` file directly), and this is why a lot of the documentation you may find won't apply if you do use `hpack`.

And in your case, the `.cabal` file is generated from `package.yaml`. This is done using the `hpack` tool which is used by default in `stack`.

It translates to file xyz.cabal, as follows:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      ...
  other-modules:
      Paths_xyz
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  ghc-options: -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , directory
  default-language: Haskell2010

executable xyz
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_genc3
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -O2 -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , directory
    , xyz
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite xyz-test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Spec.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_genc3
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , directory
    , xyz
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. In "package.yaml" there is multiple places where "dependencies:" shows up. It is the top level one where it worked.

Comment: In file “package.yaml” (top level directory of your project), “- <PackageName>” has to be placed under “dependencies:” that has no indentation, and is not below executables or tests! It (“- <PackageName>”) also has to be placed without indentation, otherwise you will get errors like (“package.yaml:23:0: did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping”).

Comment: I'll remove those spaces, but that's also just a matter of knowing that YAML is indentation-sensitive; all list elements must be indented the same, but they can be indented.

Comment: @Xia Would you mind if I would add an example to your answer?

Comment: Sure, feel free to edit my answer as you see fit.

Comment: @Xia I just tried. Unfortunately, I have got an error message: "Suggested edit queue is full".